# jQuery day and amount calculate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to insert price and days when checkbox is clicked. But if once is work another is not work properly. I want to insert price in id="amount" and days is id="days". Please give a good solution, thanks.

```
<div class="dis_process">
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="checkbox" rel="100" value="5"> <span>Gift Pack</span>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)" placeholder="100"> <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>5 days Extra</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="checkbox" rel="500" value="10"> <span>Custom Logo</span>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)" placeholder="300"> <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>10 days Extra</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="checkbox" rel="50" value="7"> <span> Color Box Packing</span>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)" placeholder="50"> <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>7 days Extra</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <p>Total Amount</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div id="amount"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="days"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
</div>
```

Comment: where is the code that is not working?

Comment: where is the javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fvgfdkqa/1/)

I believe this is what you wanted, on click you fire an event and then pull the attributes you set.  From there we are checking if the checkbox was checked or unchecked and add or subtract.

**JS**

```
// Global JS variables to store totalCost and totalDays
var totalCost = 0;
var totalDays = 0;

// Event for when any checkbox is checked
$(':checkbox').on('click', function() {
    // pull the number of days from the value of the checkbox input
    var days = $(this).val();
    // pull the cost from the attribute rel
    var cost = $(this).attr('rel');

    // see if the checkbox is checked or not add or subtract
    if(this.checked) {
        totalCost += parseInt(cost);
        totalDays += parseInt(days);
    } else {
        totalCost -= parseInt(cost)
        totalDays -= parseInt(days);
    }

    // set the text of the amount and days to the cost and days
    $('#amount').text(totalCost);
    $('.days').text(totalDays);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="dis_process">
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="checkbox" rel="100" value="5" /> 
            <span>Gift Pack</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)" placeholder="100"/> <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>5 days Extra</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="checkbox" rel="500" value="10"/> <span>Custom Logo</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)" placeholder="300"/> <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>10 days Extra</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="checkbox" rel="50" value="7"/> <span> Color Box Packing</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)" placeholder="50"/> <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>7 days Extra</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <p>Total Amount</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div id="amount"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="days"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
</div>
```